# Saving a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have used this code to extract tweets and store it in a csv file.

```
import tweepy
import csv
auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler('xxx', 'xxx')
auth.set_access_token('xx-xx', 'xxx')
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Open/create a file to append data to
csvFile = open('result.csv', 'a')

#Use csv writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q = "#Seeman").items(500):

    # Write a row to the CSV file. I use encode UTF-8
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
csvFile.close()
```

But i need to save a csv file in my local disk containing the tweets from the extracted data. How can i do it? Thanks.

Comment: Are those your real credentials?

Comment: Yep. But don't worry. I have changed them.

Comment: How exactly is this code not working? I don't think you need to `encode` the text on Python 3.

Comment: Have you checked pandas? It may not be necessary for this kind of a problem, but I feel writing to CSV is a lot more easier with that.

Comment: It's working fine. The tweets are getting printed once i call it in the cmd terminal. But i couldn't find the csv file in my local disk. I need a seperate csv file containing those tweets. That's what i'm looking for.

Comment: @MarmikShah I personally find it much easier to write the CSV file as the OP is already doing, then maybe analyse/open later in Pandas

Comment: Provide a full file path where you wanna save the csv file, or check your current working directory, you could find your csv file over there

Comment: do `import os os.getcwd()` this is the path where your current csv is stored

Comment: (or just run `pwd` from the terminal where you launch Python)

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Thanks mate!!. your code solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the working directory of your script, this is what you need to do:

```
import os 
os.getcwd()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get where the csv files are stored, this is what you need to do:

```
import os 
os.getcwd()
```